# Can't run model training: NotImplementedError

Tags: object-detection, yolov8

I am new with the Yolo and Pytorch, sorry if this is a noob question. I would like to do some image detection task using YoloV8 with training a model from beginning. Apparently I am having an error when I want to run this code:

```
from ultralytics import YOLO
model = YOLO('yolov8m.pt')
model.train(data=r'C:\spacecraft-pose-object-detection-runtime\notebooks\train\datasets\data.yaml',epochs=100,patience=20,batch=16, device = 0)
```

**I get this error:**

> NotImplementedError Traceback (most recent call last)
> Cell In[8], line 1
> 1 model.train(data=r'C:\spacecraft-pose-object-detection-runtime\notebooks\train\datasets\data.yaml',epochs=100,patience=20,batch=16, device = 0)
>
> File c:\Users\murad\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\ultralytics\engine\model.py:655, in Model.train(self, trainer, **kwargs)
> 652 pass
> 654 self.trainer.hub_session = self.session # attach optional HUB session
> 655 self.trainer.train()
> 656 # Update model and cfg after training
> 657 if RANK in (-1, 0):
>
> File c:\Users\murad\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\ultralytics\engine\trainer.py:213, in BaseTrainer.train(self)
> 210 ddp_cleanup(self, str(file))
> 212 else:
> 213 self._do_train(world_size)
>
> File c:\Users\murad\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\ultralytics\engine\trainer.py:327, in BaseTrainer._do_train(self, world_size)
> 325 if world_size > 1:
> 326 self._setup_ddp(world_size)
> 327 self._setup_train(world_size)
> 329 nb = len(self.train_loader) # number of batches
> 330 nw = max(round(self.args.warmup_epochs * nb), 100) if self.args.warmup_epochs > 0 else -1 # warmup iterations
>
> File c:\Users\murad\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\ultralytics\engine\trainer.py:271, in BaseTrainer._setup_train(self, world_size)
> ...
> PythonTLSSnapshot: registered at ..\aten\src\ATen\core\PythonFallbackKernel.cpp:162 [backend fallback]
> FuncTorchDynamicLayerFrontMode: registered at ..\aten\src\ATen\functorch\DynamicLayer.cpp:494 [backend fallback]
> PreDispatch: registered at ..\aten\src\ATen\core\PythonFallbackKernel.cpp:166 [backend fallback]
> PythonDispatcher: registered at ..\aten\src\ATen\core\PythonFallbackKernel.cpp:158 [backend fallback]

Those are the packages I have installed:

> Ultralytics YOLOv8.1.26  Python-3.11.8 torch-2.2.1+cu118 CUDA:0
> (NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1070 Ti, 8192MiB)

- torch 2.2.1+cu118
- torchaudio 2.2.1+cu118
- torchvision 0.17.1
- ultralytics 8.1.26

I would appreciate all the suggestions

I have tried to update and check all the versions of the packages but did not work.